# How to inspect MSVC's c++ object layout?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When compiling C++ code with clang, you can inspect the memory layout it generates by passing `-Xclang -fdump-record-layouts` [on the command line](https://godbolt.org/g/QdRPcN).

Is there a similar way to inspect the memory layout that MSVC generates, ideally one that works on the command line and can be used on godbolt.org?

Comment: @SergeyA uhh it does: https://godbolt.org/g/47UA3g

Comment: Wow! That's something new for me. I stand corrected.